# simple login servlet not giving output

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc

I developed simple login servlet which runs well in eclipes but i am not getting any output from server side help to fix this
used create statement not prepared statement
help to improve logic

> index.html
>
> ```html
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
> <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
> <title>welcome to Student Account</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>  <font color="red">
>   <center>
>    Welcome to Student portal <br> <b>kindly login to your acccount</b></br> <b>Login
>     form</b>
>    <form method="post" action="./Account">
>     <table>
>      <tr>
>       <td>Student Login:</td>
>       <td><input type="text" name="sname"></td>
>      </tr>
>      <tr>
>       <td>Student Password:
>       <td><input type="password" name="spasswd"></td>
>      </tr>
>      <tr>
>       <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
>        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
>        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
>       <td><input type="submit" value="login">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input
>        type="reset" value="reset"></td>
>      </tr>
>     </table>
>   </center>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> > StudentAccInfo.java

```
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.io.PrintWriter;

   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   @WebServlet("/Account")
   public class StudentAccInfo extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    String sname=request.getParameter("sname");
    String spasswd=request.getParameter("spasswd");
    String Status=UserService.validate(sname, spasswd);
    out.println("<html><body><center>");
    out.println("<font color='red' size='7'>");
    if(Status.equals("success")){
        out.println("Login Success");
    }
    if(Status.equals("failure")){
        out.println("Login failure");
    }
    out.println("</center></body></html>");     

}
```

}

> > UserService.java

```
  import java.sql.Connection;
  import java.sql.DriverManager;
  import java.sql.ResultSet;
  import java.sql.Statement;

 public class UserService {

public  static String validate(String sname, String spasswd)
{
    Connection con=null;
    Statement st=null;
    ResultSet rs=null;
    String Status="";
try{
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL", "scott", "tiger");
    st=con.createStatement();
    String sql="";
      sql=sql+"select * from std where sname=";
      sql=sql+"'"+sname+"'";
      sql=sql+" "+"and spasswd=";
      sql=sql+"'"+spasswd+"'";

      rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
      boolean b=rs.next();
      if(b==true){
          Status="success";
      }else{
          Status="failure";
      }
       }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
      }finally {
          try{
                 con.close();
                 st.close();
                 rs.close();
             }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace(); 
             }
            }
return Status;
}
}
```

Note:- I have used create Statement not prepared statement

running well but not getting output

Answer (score 1):

remove **./** from action attribute

```
<form method="post" action="Account">
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17498138)

Comment: Yes it does, i even reproduced this problem in my own IDE.